# Meterial-UI [Select] - How to remove focus when clicked outside?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a simple multiple select using Material-UI's Select component. But one thing that I did not like is that if you unselect anything or just don't select anything and click outside, the dropdown disappears but the label remains focused until you click again or focus on other component.

Any solution?

I want to remove focus from the label/select component when the menu disappears.

[image]

Link to component: https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this is not exactly what You are looking for there is important reason why those fields are kept focused (despite of being too much visibly outlined) and it is [a11y](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Accessibility).

---

Thanks to keeping focus on `<select>` element we are allowed to reselect once selected value eg. by only keyboard (this covers case when you selected bad option unintentionally and want to easily come to the select list back or - like in Yours - **easily select again if under any situation we wanted it but we closed the list before it happend**).

One important thing is that the MD's `<select>`'s focus behaviour **does not differ** from the way native select does it:

[image: Select list opened]
[image: Select list closed]

And generally should not be changed **[outlinenone.com](http://www.outlinenone.com/)** without having critical reason.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for but this worth marking as answer. I've used select a lot of time but never noticed. It is not a bug it is a feature. The reason I noticed is just because the label floating. Thanks man. Knowledge++.

Comment: Please @Xarvalus can you see the question in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978284/material-ui-select-how-to-focus-the-select-when-the-input-is-clicked?noredirect=1#comment118404403_66978284      I want to keep the focus on the parent container but I can't