# Material-UI Select, how to apply :focus-within styling on the select when the input is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the Select inside a div component:

```
<div className="custom-filter custom-filter-data">
            <DateRangeIcon className="search-icon"/>
            <FormControl variant='standard' ref={addrRef} className= 
                {classes.formControl}>                
              <Select
                labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                id="demo-simple-select"
                defaultValue=""
                onFocus={(e) => {addrRef.current.focus()}}
                displayEmpty
              >
                <MenuItem value="" disabled>
                  Seleziona data
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
              //other components
         </div>
```

css container

```
.custom-filter:focus-within{
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #80bdff;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgb(0 123 255 / 25%);
}
```

I need to trigger the focus on the select when the select input is clicked in order to leverage :focus-within styling of the parent container. Now the parent :focus-within is working just onChange event (when I select the MenuItem). as you can see, I've tried with useRef() but is not working... It seems that when a user clicks on the input of the select, it blocks all the other focus...

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-ui-select-forked-8msbu?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Can you put together a runnable example?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit more. It's hard to understand what you want. If you want to execute some code when the user clicks the `SelectInput`, attach a focus listener like this: `Select onFocus={e => console.log('focus')} />`

Comment: @NearHuscarl Thank you, i resolved the first question! Can you see the modified question to help me with the focus issue? thank you

Comment: Can you put your code on CodeSandbox?

Comment: @NearHuscarl done! thank you very very much for your reply

Comment: Are you using MUI v1? it's unsupported now and your CodeSandbox doesn't run when I tried to pass the ref to the component.

Comment: @NearHuscarl no i'm using "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3" but i can't add it to the codeSandbox :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230844/discussion-between-july-and-nearhuscarl).

Comment: @July You can find many CodeSandbox examples in both the Material-UI documentation and in many StackOverflow questions that use v4 of Material-UI. A CodeSandbox using v1 isn't helpful when that isn't what you are using.

Comment: @RyanCogswell i was able to modify the codesandbox and I updated the version to v4. As you can see the problem is the same as the v1, and I lose the focus on custom-filter div when I click the select. How can I keep the focus on the div container?

Answer (score 5):

By default, `Select` opens the popup (implemented via the `Menu` component) of its options within a [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). This means that the menu items are not descendants of your `div` in the DOM, so when focus is on the menu or menu items then the `:focus-within` selector on your `div` is not matched.

You can change this behavior by adding `MenuProps={{ disablePortal: true }}` to the `Select`.

Relevant documentation:

- https://material-ui.com/api/select/#props

  - Documents the `MenuProps` prop
- https://material-ui.com/api/modal/#props

  - Documents the `disablePortal` prop (`Menu` leverages `Popover` which leverages `Modal`)

Here's a modified version of your sandbox:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  return (
    <div className="custom-filter custom-filter-data">
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          style={{ minWidth: "100px" }}
          value={value}
          input={<Input id="age-simple" />}
          onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
          MenuProps={{ disablePortal: true }}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty........</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Select focus-within]

Comment: thank you very much!!!!!! this is what I was looking for

Comment: Can I ask you sir, if I open the menu of the select and close it by clicking outside the element, without choose any menu option, the focus stay on the parent container with this bubble effect  (blur+focus). There is a way to eliminate this effect and remove the focus when I don't choose the option and just close the menu? I've tried but without success...